# How can I insert or update a Collection objects in a table -- saveOrUpdateAll() method only tries to update not inserting any values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an issue with `saveOrUpdateAll()` method of Spring `BaseHibernateDAO`.
I am unable to insert the value. It always tries to fire the update query.
How can I insert or update a `Collection` objects in a table using `BaseHibernateDAO` of Spring

Comment: If you provide what you have tried till now, we can help you better

Comment: some code will help to find out what is your problem.

Comment: Even though you have an answer, it would still be useful to other SO users if you provide some sample code, showing us what problem the solution fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Iterate the collection and Save the object entity one by one while iterating it.

```
For(Class c : Class_collection)
{
    session.saveOrUpdate(c);
}
transaction.commit();
```

That is one way of doing it. Any DAO method's hibernate implementation would do the same internally.

This method saveOrUpdateAll() has been deprecated 
You can see it below implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/2.5.6/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.java#767)

```
public void saveOrUpdateAll(final Collection entities) throws DataAccessException {
         executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback() {
             public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
                 checkWriteOperationAllowed(session);
                 for (Iterator it = entities.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                     session.saveOrUpdate(it.next());
                 }
                 return null;
             }
         });
     }
```

Hope this solution works well for you. :)

Comment: What ever you mentioned above is right , but when I called the saveorupdate its only executing update query and not executing the insert query.

Comment: WHen I tried to do the same by calling saveorupdate() from the log I am able to see only the update query executed by hibernate and not the insert query so that I am unable to save the value . I am able to update the values. below is the log Hibernate: update GWT_PRODUCTS set SAP_MODEL_ID=?, CATEGORY_NAME=?, PARENT_CATEGORY_NAME=?, COUNTRY=?, MODEL_SEQUENCE_NUM=? where MODEL_NAME=?

Comment: Check the primary key of your entity before saving. The Primary key must be same thats the reason it must be updating the same.